# How to get redirect from HttpWebResponse?

Tags: c#, url, redirect, httpwebresponse

I am trying to get a redirect from Google Maps using a project that is currently only at .Net Framework 4.0.

Take Microsoft's mailing address as an example:

> 1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA

Format a string that replaces *Spaces*  , *Commas* <kbd>,</kbd> with *Plus* <kbd>+</kbd> signs:

https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=1+microsoft+way+redmond+wa

By the time Google finishes processing the page, the final URL has the Latitude and Longitude:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir//1+Microsoft+Way,+Redmond,+WA+98052/@47.6393095,-122.1327333,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x54906d73f7de150b:0x922499d19305e9a0!2m2!1d-122.1283559!2d47.6393096

I need the Latitude and Longitude from this URL.

I found this article already on SO:

[Get a collection of redirected URLs from HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17990604/153923)

Using the solution there, I created this very similar looking method:

```
private String latitude, longitude;

private void GetLatLongFromAddress(String p_street_name, String p_city, String p_state, String p_postal_code)
{
    var street_name = String.Format("{0}", p_street_name.Replace(' ', '+')).Trim();
    var city = String.Format("{0}", p_city).Trim();
    var state = String.Format("{0}", p_state).Trim();
    var postal_code = String.Format("{0}", p_postal_code).Trim();
    var mapUrl = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/?daddr={0}+{1}+{2}+{3}",
                               street_name, city, state, postal_code);
    var location = String.Copy(mapUrl);
    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        var req1 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(location);
        req1.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        // give page time to redirect?
        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req1.GetResponse())
        {
            location = resp.GetResponseHeader("Location");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
            {
                var postalIndex = location.IndexOf(postal_code);
                var slashAtIndex = location.IndexOf("/@") + 1;
                if ((postalIndex < slashAtIndex) && (slashAtIndex < location.Length))
                {
                    var split = location.Substring(slashAtIndex).Split(',');
                    latitude = split[0];
                    longitude = split[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see where I format the original URL with this line:

```
var mapUrl = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/?daddr={0}+{1}+{2}+{3}",
                          street_name, city, state, postal_code);
```

The problem is with this line:

```
location = resp.GetResponseHeader("Location");
```

Every time I get the response, the returned `location` value is the same as the `mapUrl` value that I started with because Google does not redirect it immediately.

I tried adding a [Sleep(5000)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) call, but that did not change anything.

How would I go about getting the final redirect?

Comment: I think your problem lies in the fact that Google does the redirect via Javascript rather than directly from the HTTP request.

Comment: @drz, that's possible. Is there a way to get the redirect using Javascript instead of the HTTP request? I'll go search on that now, but if you know something please share.

Comment: I don't know of any direct way to deal with it.  You would need something that could parse and process JS, which isn't easy